# VBA　ボタン押す→ファイル参照→ファイル名表示→次へボタン→選択した音声ファイル再生

Tags: visual-studio, vba

タイトルにあるような動作をするプログラムを作りたいです。
VisualStudio2017をつかって作成しています。
デザインのところで、ボタン（ファイル参照）、テキストボックス、ボタン（次へ）の3つを配置しています。
ネットで検索したもののよくわからずじまいでした。。。
GetOpenFilenameをつかうのかな…？程度の理解です。
調べようにも調べ方が悪いのか一向に進まないので、質問させていただきました。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: VisualStudio2017だと、VBAよりはVB.NETのような気がしますが、本当にVBAですか？ 何か参考にしたり目標にしているWeb上の記事とか、作成途中でもソースコードやスクリーンショットなどがあれば追記してみてください。

Comment: VBAではなくVB.NETでした…VBAのサンプルコードを入力するとエラー出るのでなんでだろうと思っていましたが、モノがちがうとは。ご迷惑おかけしました。お教えいただきありがとうございます！

Comment: VBAでやりたいのなら、VisualStudioではなくMS-WordとかMS-ExcelのマクロメニューからVisualBasicEditorで入力してください。VisualStudioのVB.NETでやりたいのなら、こちらの記事を参考にしてください。[【VB.Net】wavファイルを再生してみた～音源ファイルの取扱い～](https://dreamparadaisu.com/visualbasic_63/), [音(Wavファイル)を再生・停止するサンプルプログラム【VB.net】](https://www.youfit.co.jp/archives/483)

Comment: VB.NETでやろうと思ってます！わざわざサイトまで…ありがとうございますm(_ _"m)